Getting error in AWS DMS Source Test endpoint connection
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: [unixODBC]FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user"
I am trying to Implement as per this video and the article (link provided below).
When I am trying to  do connection test for source Endpoint, I am getting the above error.
But I am able to connect to the db from DMS query Editor
https://dev.to/omarrosadio/implementing-change-data-capute-cdc-with-aurora-serverless-v2-4i1l
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIqKtn2vbsU

What is DMS Query Editor?

The password that the DMS Endpoint is using is not the same one that you are connecting with when you get authenticated, however, that may be. If you are not using Secrets Manager for the password, then you may have made a typo when setting up your target endpoint.

Yes I made a typo while manually adding username and password. Its working now.
but When i use AWS Secrets Manager to Access to endpoint database, I am getting error.
"Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to build connection string Unable to find Secrets Manager secret, Application-Detailed-Message: Failed to retrieve secret. Unable to find AWS Secrets Manager secret Arn 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2-...' The secrets_manager get secret value failed: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached Too many retries: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached"

@RossBush RDS query Editor

That timeout likely indicates that there is no connectivity between your DMS Subnet and the Security Manager. You can now add a VPC Endpoint Interface to com.amazonaws..secretsmanager and then set up an ingress rules for dms and/or rds.

Yes added VPC Endpoint for secret manager

Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to build connection string Secret manager secret contains one or more unsupported characters, Application-Detailed-Message: Failed to retrieve secret. In secret Arn arn:aws:secretsmanager::secret:rds-db-credentials/cluster-abcdefghijkhasdl/xxxxxx/1714023947411-BZxSyB, secret key password contains one or more unsupported characters.
Now I am getting this error, What may be the issue
@RossBush

It sounds very much like your secret rotator is generating invalid characters to use a password for your database. You will need to exclude certain characters from being generated. For example, these characters are not valid sql server password chars ->   rotation_exclude_characters     = " ",;?*!@=\/."

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

{
"metadata": {
"timestamp": "2024-06-05T06:25:11.280660Z",
"record-type": "control",
"operation": "create-table",
"partition-key-type": "task-id",
"schema-name": "route",
"table-name": "field"
}
}
for some table i am getting this
on other tables i am getting good data
@RossBush any idea why ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78580590/getting-only-control-record-for-some-dms-task-tablemappings
ihave added all details in the link above

We had a similar very similar migration project in my company. We ended up realizing that running simple automation scripts worked faster and had less issues than using DMS.
To answer you questions:
If it is only for test, and not production I see in the link you provided that the Aurora Serverless Parameter Config isn't set or changed. Is it already accepting all required traffic types you need? Have you tested it?
If not, then I recommend using the AWS Access Analyzer to check where the bottlenecks are, or a simple temporary instance for smoke tests.
