Getting only control record for some DMS Task TableMappings
AWS DMS
Source endpoint: Aurora Postgres
Target Endpoint: Kinesis Data stream
Task with these settings
MigrationType: cdc
TableMappings: |
{"rules":[{"rule-type":"selection","rule-id":"1","rule-name":"stopobjects","object-locator":{"schema-name":"xyz","table-name":"meter"},"rule-action":"include","filters":[]}]}
Iam getting good data as below
{ "data": { "id": 139018, "name": "abcdef", "description": "Test 5th Jun2:42 PM", "producttypeid": 643005, "metertypeid": 642893, "longitude": 100, "latitude": 100, "isactive": "true", "createdby": 43989, "createdon": "2023-12-27T11:13:01.731Z", "modifiedby": 43989, "modifiedon": "2024-06-05T09:12:38.618Z" }, "metadata": { "timestamp": "2024-06-05T09:12:39.067961Z", "record-type": "data", "operation": "update", "partition-key-type": "schema-table", "schema-name": "xyz", "table-name": "meter", "transaction-id": 104129875 } }
when i point to different schema and table
{"rules":[{"rule-type":"selection","rule-id":"1","rule-name":"stopobjects","object-locator":{"schema-name":"route","table-name":"stopobject"},"rule-action":"include","filters":[]}]}
I am getting only control records
{ "timestamp": "2024-06-05T08:53:21.660141Z", "record-type": "control", "operation": "create-table", "partition-key-type": "task-id", "schema-name": "route", "table-name": "stopobject" }
and also
{ "metadata": { "timestamp": "2024-06-05T08:53:20.663690Z", "record-type": "control", "operation": "create-table", "partition-key-type": "task-id", "schema-name": "dms_control_table", "table-name": "awsdms_apply_exceptions" } }
Why I am not getting data record for the "schema-name":"route","table-name":"stopobject".

This may sound silly, did you confirm the source table has more records than what was loaded?

@RossBush Do we need to add some settings for each postgres schema for replication.
(I didnt add anything to the schema which is giving correct data)

Yes, you can include * and exclude some variant or exclude all but *. Choose a path that is least burdensome.

@RossBush i am getting the data record now, as well as getting control records .
Why am i getting control records ?

@Starlords5107 - Not too sure what you mean by Control records in this context.

@RossBush
{ "timestamp": "2024-06-05T08:53:21.660141Z", "record-type": "control", "operation": "create-table", "partition-key-type": "task-id", "schema-name": "route", "table-name": "stopobject" }
